# How to disable Windows + S shortcut in Unity

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

When I do <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> I see this effect.

[image]

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]
   (CCSM).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Click on the Ubuntu Button (in the top-left corner) and search for CompizConfig Settings Manager and open it.
3. There scroll down to **Desktop** section and look for **Expo** and click it. Click on the Expo key's key-binding and uncheck **Enable**. That will disable the expo feature. You could also alternatively assign a different key-binding to it.

[image: compizconfig]

[image: expo key-binding]

Comment: Sorry for very late reply..busy with wedding stuff :)

Comment: @javanoob no problemo :)

Comment: I have the same problema that javanob in the beginning. On Ubuntu 11.10.
I have changed it as nitstorm says and the behavior is the same. Im changed the shortcut to Super+e and then, when y stroke Super+e start expo and if i use Super+s makes the same thing (start expo).
I'v assigned Super+s key to open synaptic on Keyboard shortcut settings but always start expo plugin. Thanks,