# Disable super + s in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

I tried [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105558/how-do-i-disable-the-super-key) but it didn't work.

How can I disable `super + s` which previews workspaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable super + s on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296071/disable-super-s-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: This was 7 years ago, I don't use Linux anymore

Answer (score 3):

You can use CompizConfig to do this. (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` in a terminal to install if it isn't on your computer already)

To open, type "CompizConfig" into your Dash, or `ccsm` in the terminal.

Once it's open, scroll to the "Expo" option, which can be found in the Desktop section (I assume this is in the default plugins but cannot remember for certain)

Click on Expo, and then on the Bindings tab, look at the top option (Expo key). Click on the right, where it says "<Super>s". Then either uncheck the "Enabled" box to disable it entirely, or click "Grab key combination" and enter a different combo to change it to something else. Click OK to accept your settings and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I disabled it as you said, but with no effect.

Comment: @Radu Interesting, it seems that it's not working properly for me either - I had simply assumed this would be it (it's possible to reassign the key but the old one remains, even). Could this be a bug? (The relevant bit in `dconf-editor` - org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.expo.expo-key - is also set to "Disabled", to no avail. Most odd.

Comment: even changing the shortcut doesn't work. I tried different shortcuts but the preview is binded to `super+s` and `super+shift+s`

Comment: @Sourabh Apparently it used to work - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/62045/how-to-disable-windows-s-keystroke-in-unity - but doesn't any more. I can only assume that this is a bug of some kind...

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Compiz Config -> Expo -> Bindings -> Expo Key

Answer (score 2):

[unity](/questions/tagged/unity) in [ubuntu14.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu14.04) is interrupting any "super" key combination by default settings.

To disable workspaces preview with [super+s](/questions/tagged/super%2bs) or [meta+s](/questions/tagged/meta%2bs) (and allowing other apps to grab this shortcut) I had to:

1. Disable (or change) the Compiz "expo" plugin shortcut in [compizconfig](/questions/tagged/compizconfig) (run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager && ccsm`) in `Desktop > expo > binding > expo key`
2. Change the unity dash key (from  to anything else you like) to prevent it to interrupt all "super+..." bindings (again in CompizConfig) in `Desktop > Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Launcher > Key to show the Dash, Launcher and Help Overlay`. I set it to [control+super] to still be able to hit it with a single finger.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dconf-editor`, set `org.gnome.shell.keybindings.toggle-overview` to `[]`.